# angularFireAuth does not work with google

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I try to use firebase with angularjs to authenticate users.
Everything works fine except with google. (classic, facebook and twitter works great).

This a sample of my code :

I try to understand where the problem by displaying the error in the console :

```
    angularFireAuth.login(provider, {
        email: userEmail,
        password: userPassword
    }).then(function(user) {
        //Success
    }, function(error) {
        //Error
        console.error('Login failed: ', error);
    });
```

The error object contains a message: "Invalid JWT"

I searched the web but I did not find any explanation for this error.

One of you could enlighten me?

In advance, thank you.

Comment: Have you:
1. Enabled Google auth in your Firebase Dashboard?
2. Set up in your Google project the authorized origin and callback URL? (https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/simple-login-google.html)

Comment: Yes I followed the procedure to the letter .

Comment: Why are you using `email` and `password` with Google Simple Login? That method only needs `provider`. Remove those and try this: `angularFireAuth.$login(provider).then(...`

Comment: I use the classic connection too, this explains it ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that everything is OK with your Google app and `angularFireAuth` is:

```
$scope.angularFireAuth = $firebaseSimpleLogin(<YOUR_FIREBASE_REF>);
```

(You could read more about AngularJS login over [here](https://www.firebase.com/docs/angular/reference.html#firebasesimplelogin))

You should try this:

```
$scope.angularFireAuth.$login(provider) // Your code is missing '$' before login.
  .then(function(user) {
    //Success
  }, function(error) {
    //Error
    console.error('Login failed: ', error);
});
```

You don't need to use `email` nor `password` due to you're trying to log in with [Google](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/simple-login-google.html) not with an [Email](https://www.firebase.com/docs/security/simple-login-email-password.html)

I hope it helps you.

Comment: You raise an important point, I did not use the syntax angularFire. Too hastily. I all over again, and I no longer have the problem. thank you